# Indentation after adding value in Xml node with children

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

After adding XML-value in XML-node, indentation becomes broken and all children of the current XML-node start to look ugly and not readable at all, but XML-file is still valid and my XML-scanner works fine.

[Example of using XML-File which has no XML-value in XML-node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3wwn.png)

[Example of using XML-File which has XML-value in XML-node and children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfUhb.png)

Here we go!

```
public class XmlNodeSerializer : INodeSerializer
{
    private readonly XmlTextWriter _xmlWriter;

    public XmlNodeSerializer(TextWriter writer)
    {
        if(writer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(writer)}");

        _xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(writer);
        _xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    }

    public void Serialize(Node node)
    {
        if(node == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(node)}");

        using (_xmlWriter)
        {
            _xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
            WriteXmlNode(node, _xmlWriter);
            _xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
        }
    }

    private static void WriteXmlNode(Node target, XmlWriter wr)
    {
        wr.WriteStartElement(target.Name);

        if (target.HasAttributes())
            foreach (var attr in target.Attributes)
                wr.WriteAttributeString(attr.Key, attr.Value);

        if(target.HasValue())
            wr.WriteValue(target.Value);

        if (target.HasChildren())
            foreach (var child in target.Children)
                WriteXmlNode(child, wr);

        wr.WriteEndElement();
    }
```

Comment: 1) What is your question exactly, given that *XML-file is still valid and my XML-scanner works fine.*?  2) According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx), `XmlTextWriter` is deprecated.  You should use [`XmlWriter.Create()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.create(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.  Does that fix your problem?  3) Can you create a [mcve] (a console app) for your problem?  You include code (good!) but we don't have `INodeSerializer` or `Node` so we can't run your code.

Comment: Your code is broken, btw, as you shouldn't have a `using (_xmlWriter)` on an object that is created when it is constructed. You should create the instance in the `using` statement itself.

Comment: In the absence of a [mcve] this might be explained by the [documentation for `XmlTextWriter.Formatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.formatting(v=vs.110).aspx): *If the Indented option is set, child elements are indented using the Indentation and IndentChar properties. **Only element content is indented**. ... Writing any text content, excluding String.Empty puts that element into mixed content mode*.  Thus, writing a non-empty text value disables indenting for its element because the element now contains mixed content.